# when I starting anchor test --skip-deploy I face an issue like this:"needs an import attribute of type "json""

Tags: anchor, solana-program

TypeError: Module "file:///mnt/d/Path/tsconfig.json" needs an import attribute of type "json"
at validateAttributes (node:internal/modules/esm/assert:89:15)
at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:132:3)
at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:13)
at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:56)
at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:65:26)
at ModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:303:17)
at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:260:34)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:241:17)
at ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:328:23)
at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:430:15)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: This is a problem with typescript not Solana - it seems your tsconfig is not formatted correctly, double check that it's valid JSON.